# Testing vuex mocked mutation with jest

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vuex

I have been testing my vuex store with the following structure

**/src/store.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = {
  data: []
};

export const mutations = {
  SET_DATA(state, data) {
    state.data = data;
  }
};

export const actions = {
  fetchData({ commit }) {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => commit(SET_DATA, data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
});
```

My test file for actions asserts for the url and commit triggering

```
it("should fetch correct data and commit to store", () => {
    // Mock fetch
    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        status: 200,
        json: () => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(mockData))
      })
    );

    return store.dispatch("fetchData").then(() => {
      expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
      );
      expect(mockSetData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

Currently my test passes only for URL and does not call `mockSetData` which is a jest mocked function.

I'm new to TDD and not quite sure why this fails. [Here's an implementation on codesandbox for more context](https://codesandbox.io/s/z27y95694x?previewwindow=tests)